# Constructor values not being applied on startup

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I've recently made a volumetric rendering system in hope to use them for particle effects, whilst attempting a dust emitter, i noticed that the positioning of the particles was completely wrong. I generate seeded random numbers which i feed into each individual particle in order to set the position. When i start debugging as normal, the particles will only spawn on top of one another in two positions. When applying a breakpoint and stepping though the loop one particle at a time and then continuing on, each particle was in its assigned random position. In addition to this, whilst testing the problem on a large particle pool, i used a hitcount to break the loop on a certain number, and found that when this occurs it only initialises them to one to the two aforementioned positions. What could be causing this?

```
VolumetricDust::VolumetricDust(string type, Transform* transform, ID3D11Device* pDevice, int width, int height, int depth, bool instanceFlag, int instanceCount)
{

  for (int i = 0; i < POOL_SIZE; i++)
 {
    // PROBLEM LOOP
    particles_[i] = new ParticleVolume("Resources\\nucleon.raw", transform, width, height, depth, instanceFlag, instanceCount);
    particles_[i]->Initialise(pDevice);

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    int test = (rand() % 100 + 1);
    int test1 = rand() % 30 + 1;
    int test2 = rand() % 50 + 1;

    particles_[i]->SetVelocity(XMFLOAT3(0.0f, (float)test, 0.0f));
    particles_[i]->GetTransform()->SetPosition((float)test, (float)test1, (float)test2);


  }

 posReset = transform;
 _transform = transform;

 mWidth = width;
 mHeight = height;
 mDepth = depth;

 isInstance = instanceFlag;
 instanceNum = instanceCount;

_currentTime = 0.0f;
_spawnTime = 5.0f;
_newTime = 0.1f;
_dustTime = 0.0f;
particleTime = 5.0f;
_type = type;
_pd3dDevice = pDevice;
}

void VolumetricDust::SpawnEmitter()
{

for (int i = 0; i < POOL_SIZE; i++)
{
    if (!particles_[i]->GetParticleOn())
    {

        particles_[i]->SetParticleOn(true);
        break;
    }

}

}

void VolumetricDust::Update(float dt, Camera* cam)
{
_transform->Update();
_currentTime += dt;
_dustTime += dt;


for (int i = 0; i < POOL_SIZE; i++)
{
    SpawnEmitter();

    if (particles_[i]->GetParticleOn())
    {

        //posReset->SetPosition(XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

        particles_[i]->Update(dt, cam, posReset->GetPosition());
    }

    if (_transform)
    {
        _transform->Update();
    }

}



}

void VolumetricDust::Draw(ID3D11DeviceContext * _pImmediateContext, ConstantBuffer3D & cb, ID3D11Buffer* _pConstantBuffer)
{
 for (int i = 0; i < POOL_SIZE; i++)
 {
    if (particles_[i]->GetParticleOn())
    {
        particles_[i]->Draw(_pImmediateContext, cb, _pConstantBuffer);
    }

 }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call `srand` only once.

When  you call it in a loop like this, the odds are very high that you get the same time value each round. That resets the random numbers, and you will get the same result for most, if not all, points.

Stopping in the debugger will let the real time change between calls to `time`, and you get separate random values because the seed will now be different.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've only recently started using srand, and i wasn't aware of this!

Comment: You should consider using [<random>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) instead of the legacy ``rand`` / ``srand`` functions